# How do I dynamically set the selected option of a drop-down list using jQuery, JavaScript and HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For some reason, I can't get this to work.

My options list is populated dynamically using these scripts:

```
function addOption(selectId, value, text, selected) {
    var html = '<option value="'+value+'">'+text+'</option>';
    if (selected == "on") {
        html = '<option value="'+value+'" selected="selected">'+text+'</option>';
    }
    $('#'+selectId).append(html);
}

function addSalespersonOption(id, name, defsales) {
    addOption('salesperson', id, name, defsales);
}
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<td class="text-r"><label for="salesperson">Salesperson:</label></td>
<td>
    <select id="salesperson">
        <option value="">(select)</option>
    </select>
</td>
```

So far, the output is:

```
<option value="1266852143634" selected="selected">Eric Hunt</option>
```

The DOM shows this:

```
index              2
disabled           false
value              "1266852143634"
text               "Eric Hunt"
selected           false
defaultSelected    true
```

But for some reason, when the page is loaded, the dropdown does not display Eric Hunt as pre selected. Nor is anything for that matter.

How can I get "selected true" instead of "defaultSelected true"?

---

EDIT: As it turns out, the above code works perfectly, thanks to the help of [deceze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/476/deceze) and [rosscj2533](https://stackoverflow.com/users/225085/rosscj2533)'s answers from below. The only reason it's not working for me is, I found Ruby code that was overwriting the select elements.

Thanks for everyone's help on this,

Cheers

Comment: Your `addOption` function seems pretty weird. The first time you call it like a function, the second time you're passing it to `$()` like an object, that's probably where your problem is. Just to make sure I understand what you want to do: You're trying to insert a new option into an existing `select` element and make that option selected, right?

Comment: The function addSalespersonOption(id, name, defsales) {
        addOption('salesperson', id, name, defsales);
is dynamically building a list of options from stored data to be used in the select element.
The if statement was my attempt to determine witch one of those options will display as the default selection in the select element.
like we would if we were to hard code the select element. <option select="selected></option>

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The `defaultSelected` attribute is not settable, it's just for informational purposes:

[Quote](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_option_defaultselected.asp):

> The defaultSelected property returns the default value of the selected attribute.
>   This property returns true if an option is selected by default, otherwise it returns false.

I think you want:

```
$('option[value=valueToSelect]', newOption).attr('selected', 'selected');
```

I.e. set the `selected` attribute of the `option` you want to select.

---

Without trying to fix your code, here's roughly how I would do it:

```
function buildSelect(options, default) {
    // assume options = { value1 : 'Name 1', value2 : 'Name 2', ... }
    //        default = 'value1'

    var $select = $('<select></select>');
    var $option;

    for (var val in options) {
        $option = $('<option value="' + val + '">' + options[val] + '</option>');
        if (val == default) {
            $option.attr('selected', 'selected');
        }
        $select.append($option);
    }

    return $select;
}
```

You seem to have a lot of baggage and dependencies already and I can't tell you how to best integrate the selected option into your code without seeing more of it, but hopefully this helps.

Comment: I found another function that was part of this problem. So, I reworded the above question to include the function and hopefully it make more sense. Thanks for all your help so far.

Comment: This does add a selected attribute to the drop down, but will not show it's value in the text field.

Answer (score 9):

SCRIPT

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $("#gender").val("Male").attr("selected","selected");
    });
 </script>
```

HTML

```
<select id="gender" selected="selected">
    <option>--Select--</option>
    <option value="1">Male</option>
    <option value="2">Female</option>
</select>
```

[Click Here More Details](http://peakfinders.blogspot.in/2015/10/how-do-i-dynamically-set-selected.html)

Answer (score 5):

Here it goes.

```js
// Select by value
$('select[name="options"]').find('option[value="3"]').attr("selected",true);

// Select by text
//$('select[name="options"]').find('option:contains("Third")').attr("selected",true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>
<select name="options">
      <option value="1">First</option>
      <option value="2">Second</option>
      <option value="3">Third</option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way you can change the selected option of a `<select>` element in javascript. You can use

document.getElementById('salesperson').selectedIndex=1;

Setting it to 1 will make the second element of the dropdown selected. The select element index start from 0.

Here is a sample code. Check if you can use this type of approach:

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript">

function changeSelected() { 
document.getElementById('salesperson').selectedIndex=1;

} 

</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="f1">

<select id="salesperson" > 
   <option value"">james</option>
   <option value"">john</option>  
</select> 
<input type="button" value="Change Selected" onClick="changeSelected();">

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code works for me.  When does `addSalespersonOption` get called?  There may be a problem with that call.

Also some of your html is a bit off (maybe copy/paste problem?), but that didn't seem to cause any problems. Your select should look like this:

```
<select id="salesperson"> 
    <option value="">(select)</option> 
</select>
```

instead of this:

```
<select id="salesperson" /> 
    <option value"">(select)</option> 
</select>
```

Edit: When does your options list get dynamically populated?  Are you sure you are passing `'on'` for the `defSales` value in your call to `addSalespersonOption`?  Try changing that code to this:

```
if (selected == "on") { 
    alert('setting default selected option to ' + text);
    html = '<option value="'+value+'" selected="selected">'+text+'</option>'; 
}
```

and see if the alert happens and what is says if it does happen.

Edit: [Working example](http://jsbin.com/asumu3/2/) of my testing (the error:undefined is from jsbin, not my code).

Comment: I don't know how to find out when addSalespersonOption gets called. Thanks for the typo correction.

Comment: Ok, Yes, the alert reads: "setting default selected option to Eric Hunt".

Comment: Hmmm, well it seems like that should work for you.  I can't tell much more without seeing the rest of your code.  I'll post a working example and see if you can tell any difference between it and your code.

Comment: Thanks rosscj2533, I've never seen an editor like the one you use for the "Working example" before. good stuff. is that open to the public foe use?

Comment: Yes it is, just go to http://jsbin.com/ and you can put in any html source with javascript, then click create public link to give anyone access to it.  It's real helpful for little demos like the one I posted.  Glad you found your problem!

Answer (score 1):

Pardon my ignorance, but why are you using `$('.salesperson')` instead of `$('#salesperson')` when dealing with an ID?

Comment: Because I'm new and don't know what I'm doing!

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is wrong.

You need to call [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) with two parameters, like this:

```
$('.salesperson', newOption).attr('defaultSelected', "selected");
```

Your current code assigns the value `"selected"` to the variable `defaultSelected`, then passes that value to the `attr` function, which will then return the value of the `selected` attribute.

Comment: Thanks, But no luck. I have also tried $('.salesperson', addOption).attr('defaultSelected', true);

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select the option on the server side you can do something like:

```html
<select name="catigory">
  {{$catig := .product.Catigory}}
  <option value="computers"{{if eq $catig "computers"}} selected {{end}}>computers</option>
  <option value="mobiles"  {{if eq $catig "mobiles"}} selected {{end}}>mobiles</option>          
  <option value="motors"   {{if eq $catig "motors"}} selected {{end}}>motors</option>       
  <option value="animals"  {{if eq $catig "animals"}} selected {{end}}>animals</option>                                                  
  <option value="cars"     {{if eq $catig "cars"}} selected {{end}}>cars</option>                                                        
  <option value="services" {{if eq $catig "services"}} selected {{end}}>services</option>                                                
  <option value="others"   {{if eq $catig "others"}} selected {{end}}>others</option>            
</select>
```

This expression is specific to golang Temple. You can convert it to any template engine you wish.